# Class Symfony\Bundle\AsseticBundle\AsseticBundle not found

Tags: php, jenkins, symfony, assetic

I installed a fresh copy of symfony 3.1.6 on my local machine and i created a simple project and every thing go well but when i created a job on jenkins an launching a build i got this error :

> [RuntimeException]
>   An error occurred when executing the "'cache:clear --no-warmup'"
>   command:
>   PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Symfony\Bundle\AsseticBundle\AsseticBundle'
>   not found in
>   /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/projectfolder/app/AppKernel.php
>   on line 29

this is my composer file :

```
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.5.9",
    "symfony/symfony": "3.1.*",
    "doctrine/orm": "^2.5",
    "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "^1.6",
    "doctrine/doctrine-cache-bundle": "^1.2",
    "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "^2.3",
    "symfony/monolog-bundle": "^2.8",
    "symfony/polyfill-apcu": "^1.0",
    "sensio/distribution-bundle": "^5.0",
    "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "^3.0.2",
    "incenteev/composer-parameter-handler": "^2.0",
    "sonata-project/admin-bundle": "^3.9",
    "sonata-project/doctrine-orm-admin-bundle": "^3.1",
    "friendsofsymfony/user-bundle": "~2.0@dev",
    "sonata-project/easy-extends-bundle": "^2.1",
    "sonata-project/classification-bundle": "^3.1",
    "sonata-project/core-bundle": "^3.1",
    "sonata-project/media-bundle": "^3.3",
    "symfony/assetic-bundle": "^2.8"
},
```

any help? any idea?

Comment: check /vendor to make sure it's installed

Comment: I have a folder named vendor not vendors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the '.composer' folder is not writable on the server,so i give it 777

```
chmod 777 -R .composer
```

and i resolved the problem !

Answer (score 0):

In my fresh Symfony3 project I am using assets and I have no assetic bundle in my composer.json:

```
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.5.9",
    "symfony/symfony": "3.1.*",
    "doctrine/orm": "^2.5",
    "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "^1.6",
    "doctrine/doctrine-cache-bundle": "^1.2",
    "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "^2.3",
    "symfony/monolog-bundle": "^2.8",
    "symfony/polyfill-apcu": "^1.0",
    "sensio/distribution-bundle": "^5.0",
    "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "^3.0.2",
    "incenteev/composer-parameter-handler": "^2.0",
    "devio/pipedrive": "^1.0",
    "google/recaptcha": "~1.1",
    "friendsofsymfony/user-bundle": "~2.0@dev"
},
```

What is your purpose? If you just need to use assets in template with {{asset()}}, then you don't need this bundle. Its included, try it out.

Comment: Checkout /vendor/composer/autoload_psr4.php

Comment: There should be a row with 'Symfony\\Bundle\\AsseticBundle\\' => array($vendorDir . '/symfony/assetic-bundle'), in it. If not, run composer install again

Comment: it can be a solution but i need this bundle :(

Comment: First check if vendor/symfony/assetic-bundle exists. Then check if in vendor/composer/autoload_psr4.php the row I mentioned above exists. If not, you need to run composer install again